# Unhandled Exception firebase_functions UNAVAILABLE (flutter)

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-functions

"I have a problem using Firebase Functions emulator with Firestore. It was working fine, but when I deleted my previous project and created a new one in a different folder, and installed the necessary packages, I encountered the following error:

[image]

Please note that:

[image]

here is package.json

[image]

index.js

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.listFruit = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return ["Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Fig", "Grapes"]
});
```

code

```
HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('listFruit');
                      final results = await callable();
                      List fruit = results.data;  // ["Apple", "Banana", "Cher
                      print(fruit);
```